# store a matrix created by a function opengl

Tags: opengl, matrix

I was wondering if there is an easy way to store a created matrix into a variable to be later called by glLoadMatrix(), the point being to reset the matrix to an earlier state.

For example:

```
void reshape(int w, int h){
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(dist, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(x_shift, y_shift, z_shift);
}
```

The goal being to store the matrix produced into a separate variable to effectively save the current matrix state before multiplying on top of it.

Comment: Don't use the GL matrix stack, it is deprecated since years. Switching to some matrix library like [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) will automatically solve your issue.

Comment: Ahh, this is a small piece of a homework assignment based off an example structure. I'll take a look at glm, but I'm not sure if using an outside library will go over well with my professor.

Comment: @JustKeepSwimming: Tell your professor that the OpenGL matrix stack was never used by any serious program; it's just to cumbersome to work with. OpenGL-2 tried to get rid of it, OpenGL-3 finally did. For what it's worth, using a proper matrix math library, like GLM just redistributes responsibilities, but doesn't make you cheat.

Comment: @JustKeepSwimming: Oh, another thing for your professor to ponder about: The company I cofounded will be hiring interns soon, but we only want "the best" and there will be an exam on graphics programming. Any applicant who just writes as much as glLoadIdentity gets negative points and finds himself on the short track into the round filing basket immediately

Comment: I couldn't help but laugh at your second comment, since I have two glLoadIdentity() functions. I pulled the example code straight out of the opengl programming guide for opengl 3.0 / 3.1, and both load identity's were given in the example code. If you guys have additional resources that I could look through to potentially make learning / writing opengl code easier, I'd love to have those so I at least know what the more efficient alternatives are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already recommendet to stop using the GL matrix stack at all. It is depracted and has been removed from the core profile of modern OpenGL. Libraries like [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) could be used instead.

However, what you ask for can be done with the matrix stack. Just use [`glGetFloatv()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGet.xml) with `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix, `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` or `GL_TEXTURE_MATRIX` to query the current the respective matrix:

```
GLfloat m[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
// other GL code modifying the MODELVIEW matrix
// ...
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // make sure we restore to MODELVIEW
glLoadMatrixf(m); // restore it
```

Answer (score 0):

With the legacy functionality you are using, matrices are managed as a stack. Or to be precise, as a separate stack for each of the 4 matrix modes, where the most commonly used ones are `GL_MODELVIEW` and `GL_PROJECTION`.

The most direct way to save/restore matrices is by using the actual stack operations on this matrix stack, which is done with `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`, where `Push` and `Pop` follow the usual stack semantics:

- `Push`: Adds a stack entry by copying the current top entry.
- `Pop`: Removes the current top entry.

Let's say you first set up a matrix 1, then matrix 2, and then want to restore matrix 1. For illustration, I'll set up matrix 1 as a rotation matrix, and matrix 2 as a translation matrix, but they can of course be anything.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(...);
// This is our matrix 1, now on top of the stack.
glPushMatrix();
// Push a new stack entry, to save matrix 1.
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(...);
// Now we have matrix 2 on top of the stack.
glPopMatrix();
// Since we popped the top entry (matrix 2) off the stack, matrix 1 is
// now the active matrix at the top of the stack again.
```

You can also use `glGetFloatf(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...)` and `glGetFloatf(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ...)` to get the current matrix, and later set them again with `glLoadMatrix()`. But if you care about performance at all, you should really avoid `glGet*()` calls.